# Networking: port listening but nc fails

Tags: networking, nc, port, ss

I have set up a `docker-compose` stack on a server.

One of its services is `jaeger collector` and is configured as follows:

```
  collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.8
    environment:
      - SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
      - ES_SERVER_URLS=http://some-elk-address:9200
    ports:
      - "14269"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "14267"
      - "14250"
      - "9411:9411"
```

From my machine:

```
$ nc -zv -w 2 server-hostname 9411
nc: connect to server-hostname port 9411 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

However, from within that server:

```
# ss -tula | grep 9411
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    :::9411                 :::*
```

Comment: I think that should this was a firewall issue, I would get a time out, rather than a `Connection refused`

Comment: Iptables can do either, depending on the rules in place and the policies of the sysadmin.

Comment: you are right; it is just a fresh ubuntu 16.04 installation with no messing of `iptables` whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely related to (as the `ss` output above clearly hints) that the service is only listening for IPv6 connections

```
root@server-hostname:~/# ss -tula -4 | grep 9411
root@server-hostname:~/# ss -tula -6 | grep 9411
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    :::9411                 :::*
```